# Best Practice to implement a Bottom Navigation Bar in Xamarin Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to implement Bottom Navigation Bar in Xamarin Android. i tried to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IP9TvolZ80&t=145s

but could not able to implement cos My visual studio is targeting API 23 so i could not install API 25 latest nuget of Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.

How can i upgrade API 23 to 25 in Visual studio 2017 Community/Enterprise Edition?

Or what would be best practice to Implement Bottom Navigation Bar in Xamarin.Android on API level 23?

Comment: In your project Solution Explorer, double click your Project Properties -> Application -> Compile using Android version -> Nougat 25, your Android choose the API 25.

Comment: I am getting only latest version as Use Latest Platform (Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)) only. :(

Comment: you need to download android 7 sdk with the android SDK manager (there is a button in the VS toolbar to open it)